# The best way to check given value on unique in database with .NET Core

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following controller's action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm]LanguageViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    var newLanguage = new Language()
    {
        Sort = viewModel.Sort,
        LangCode = viewModel.Code,
        LangName = viewModel.Name
    };

    await _languageRepository.SaveAsync(newLanguage);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And the following `viewModel`:

```
public class LanguageViewModel
{
    public int Sort { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Language code is required")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Language name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Note, that `LanguageViewModel` is not my domain (Entity framework) object. For map on my database I have another one:

```
public class Language
{
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }

    public int Sort { get; set; }

    public string LangName { get; set; }

    public string LangCode { get; set; }
}
```

So, I'm working with ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1 and I need to check if `Language` with given code already exists or not. If it exists, I would like to show validation error about it. You can say that I can solve it like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm] LanguageViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    var lang = await _languageRepository.All.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x =>
        x.LangCode.ToUpper() == viewModel.Code.ToUpper());

    if (lang != null)
    {
        ModelState.TryAddModelError("Code", $"The language with code {viewModel.Code} already exists");
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    var newLanguage = new Language()
    {
        Sort = viewModel.Sort,
        LangCode = viewModel.Code,
        LangName = viewModel.Name
    };

    await _languageRepository.SaveAsync(newLanguage);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Ok. it works. But it's ugly :( Maybe there is better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that would be a little bit cleaner solution.

```
if (_languageRepository.Any(o => o.LangCode.Equals(txnId, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))) 
{
    ModelState.TryAddModelError("Code", $"The language with code {viewModel.Code} already exists");
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it not solves the problem. I will have redundant code in my action. I will show you nice example how to solve this in another web framework. Please, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic. It would be grade to have something like that in ASP .NET. Note, code in the example not in action. It's in a special file with validaton rules.

Comment: Have you tried implementing IValidatableObject in your model and writing down some custom validations in Validate method? In that way you will not overload your controller method with unnecessary validations. Ref.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ivalidatableobject

Answer (score 0):

Better to try this introduced after EF Core 5:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations

```
[Index(nameof(Url), IsUnique = true)]
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```